# problem with hyphenation with diacritic XeLaTex

Tags: polyglossia

I am type-setting with XeLaTeX using polyglossia with Czech. I encountered a problem with hyphenation the word "výstupní" at the endline is typesetted as "vy-/'stupní" but correct should be "vý-/stupní" ... so the stroke travelled at the beginning of the next line. Any suggestion?

CODE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\pagestyle{headings}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{90pt} \setlength{\textwidth}{400pt}

\usepackage{polyglossia} % Balík pro podporu vícejazyčné sazby.
\setmainlanguage{czech} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\def\uv#1{„#1“} % Definice makra pro sazbu českých uvozovek.

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\input epsf

\def\figurename{{\bf Obrázek}}
\def\tablename{{\bf Tabulka}}

\makeindex
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\newtheorem{definice}{Definice}[chapter]
\newcommand{\grad}{\mathop{\rm grad}\nolimits}

\def\tucne #1
  {\mbox{\boldmath $#1$} }


\def\souhrn #1
  {{{{\paragraph{Shrnutí}\hspace{1cm} \suma{}\\} #1} }}

\def\cile #1
 {{\bf Cíle kapitoly}:\\
   #1
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Pevné látky}
\cile{
 - ukázat strukturu pevných látek\\
 }
\\
Libovolný text.

Energie fotonu $h\nu$ se tedy transformuje do kinetické energie
elektronu $E_k$ a výstupní práce $W$
\begin{equation}
    h\nu = E_k + W.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't happen if I change `y+U0301` into U+00FD (the precomposed character).

Comment: well the issue is that i have rather long textbook and I do not want to manually change/fix this issue (it will also worsen readability of the source code)

Answer (score 2):

Add `\XeTeXinputnormalization=1` before `\begin{document}`.

In general, it's better to use the precomposed characters instead of the combining accents.